# How to change Exomedia's default video control bar's color?

Tags: java, android, colors

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:EMVideoView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/MUVCastleRock">

<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.EMVideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    EMVideoView:useDefaultControls="true" />
```

How do I change the color of the default controls (where you would see the play button)? I don't want to change the background behind the video, but instead the play bar. This is because my background is grey and so I want to change the color so that the bar is more visible.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Can you screenshot the current one, i might have a solution

Comment: @Shank I've added in a screenshot above.

Comment: Do you have access to `/exomedia/ui/widget/VideoControls.java`? 
You can replace the images for `playPauseButton` `previousButton` `nextButton` there

Comment: Yes! I think you misunderstood my question a bit, I didn't need to change the buttons themselves. I was trying to change the color of the ViewGroup containing the video controls. Looking at the class you pointed out actually helped me to solve my problem. If you would like me to credit you, please submit an answer including my findings below. Otherwise, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that I can help, you can select ur answer. As it might come in handy for the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shank suggested that I replace the images of the buttons in /exomedia/ui/widget/VideoControls.java

Although, I wasn't trying to change the images of these buttons, analyzing this class lead to my answer.

There are several functions within this class to change the settings of the default video controls.

You can set a title, description, subtitle, change out the button images (as Shank suggested), and solve my particular problem by changing the characteristics of the containers that contain the video controls (named controlsContainer).

The default container is initialized in retrieveViews() by the line:

```
controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_interactive_container);
```

Using this, I simply called this reference from my EMVideoView and changed the color as appropriate:

```
emVideoView = (EMVideoView) myView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
ViewGroup textContainer = (ViewGroup) emVideoView.findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_interactive_container);
textContainer.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.myColor));
```

Other useful methods that I discovered were as such:

```
emVideoView.getVideoControls().setTitle("title");
emVideoView.getVideoControls().setDescription("description");
emVideoView.getVideoControls().setSubTitle("sub");
emVideoView.getVideoControls().setPlayPauseImages(R.drawable.logo,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```